# How to find out whether a nested document is an actual subschema or just an object in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose, nested, updating, mixed

I have the following situation:
I am creating a general purpose update function for my project, which takes payload and goes through it, checking whether property in payload exists on model schema and if it does it assigns the new property value to document (updating it). It does this also in subdocuments (recursively).
I have a custom defined type Language for multi-language string fields, which is an object that contains properties in form of language ('en', 'de', etc). Now since its a custom type, Mongoose doesn't know if its contents were modified, so I have to use markModified on it. And here comes the problem: Actual subschemas behave here differently than objects. If I call markModified on subschema, it expects path within that subschema, not entire document. On the other hand, if I call markModified on an object, it expect entire path from parent. I don't know whether it is a bug or not, but if I want to support both, I need to differentiate between the two in my function. Is there a way to know whether it's a subschema made by user or just an object (that was converted to subschema by mongoose)?

Example setup model:

```js
    const TestSchema = new Schema(
      {
        object: {
          name: {
            type: Language
          }
        },
        nestedSchema: {
          type: NestedTestSchema
        }
      }
    )

    const NestedTestSchema = new Schema(
      {
        name: {
          type: Language
        }
      }
    )
```

Example code:

```js
      const testDocument = new TestModel({
        object: {
          name: {
            en: 'NameEN',
            de: 'NameDE'
          }
        }
        nestedSchema: {
          name: {
            en: 'NameEN',
            de: 'NameDE'
          }
        }
      })

      // We make a payload to change these values

      const payload = {
        object: { // Update object
          name: {
            en: 'Name updated',
            fr: 'Something',
          }
        },
        nestedSchema: { // Update subschema
          name: {
            en: 'Name updated',
            fr: 'Something',
          }
        }
      }
```

And now when I receive this and update the document with these values, for object I have to

```js
const { object, nestedSchema } = document // This, of course, is useless here, I would get nestedSchema and object as argument in recursive function, its only for demonstration
nestedSchema.markModified('name.en') // Etc
```

and for object I have to

```js
object.markModified('object.name.en') // Etc
```

Answer (score 0):

Together with co-workers we found out that object is not an actual subschema, it's called a [nestedPath](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html#subdocuments-versus-nested-paths). Only nestedPaths have property `$__isNested`, subschemas don't. As a result, because of this different handling of two cases, in nestedPaths we need to specify full path when using `markModified` while in subschemas only path within that subschema